# Random Variable X and Y has a joint probability density function. Find $P(x | y)(x | y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Random Variable X and Y has a joint probability density function.

$$f_{X, Y} (x, y) =\begin{cases} 
c(x + 3y)& 3 \leq x \leq 7, 4 \leq y \leq10\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise }\\
\end{cases}
$$

(a) Find $f_{X | Y}(x | y)$

(b) $P(x \leq 5 | Y = 9)$

---

My attempt:

$f_{X | Y}(x | y) = \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}$

$$f_Y(y) = c\int_{3}^{7}(x+3y)dx = c\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + 3xy \right)\bigg|_{3}^{7} = c(20+12y)$$

for $f_Y(y)$ has support $4 \leq y \leq 10$, 0 otherwise

$$P_{X | Y}(x | y) = \frac{c(x+3y)}{c(20+12y)} = \frac{(x+3y)}{(20+12y)}$$

$P_{X | Y}(x | y)$ has support ...

(b)

$f_{X | Y}(x | y = 9) = \frac{x + 3 \cdot 9}{20 + 12 \cdot 9} = \frac{x+27}{128}$

$$P(x \leq 5 | Y = 9) = \int_{3}^{5} f_{X | Y}(x | y = 9)dx = \int_{3}^{5} \frac{x+27}{128} = \int_{3}^{5} \left(x/128 + 27/128 \right)dx = \left(\frac{x^2}{256} + \frac{27}{128}x \right)\bigg|_{3}^{5} = \frac{31}{64}$$

Not sure if I'm right, and a question if it were the joint pdf as

$$f_{X, Y} (x, y) =\begin{cases} 
c(x + 3y)& 3 \leq x \leq y, 4 \leq y \leq10\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise }\\
\end{cases}
$$

How would the integral for the first question look like?

Comment: The first part looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.   Don't forget, however, to indicate the supports.

(Well, assuming $P_{X\mid Y}$ is conditional probability density function; why did they use $P$ rather than $f$?)

---

If instead $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c(x+2y)\,\mathbf 1_{3<x<y, 4<y<10}$, then $$f_Y(y)~{=\int_3^y c(x+2y)\mathbf 1_{4<y<10}\,\mathsf d x \\= c(\tfrac 52y^2-6y-\tfrac 92)\,\mathbf 1_{4<y<10}}$$

Comment: What would I put for the support for $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$?

Comment: The same as the support for the joint density function. @Basbas .